# Let $\{(X_i, p_i)\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of based Hausdorff spaces. Show that $\bigvee_{i \in I}X_i$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $\{(X_i, p_i)\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of based Hausdorff spaces. Show that $\bigvee_{i \in I}X_i$ is Hausdorff

I tried to prove this but ended up getting stuck. Basically the idea I had was the following. By definition we have that $$\bigvee_{i \in I}X_i = \bigsqcup_{i \in I}X_i / \{p_i \ | \ i\in I\}$$ and we know that $\bigsqcup_{i \in I}X_i$ is Hausdorff. So now pick two points $x, y \in \bigvee_{i \in I}X_i$. Then consider the quotient map $$q : \bigsqcup_{i \in I}X_i \to \bigsqcup_{i \in I}X_i / \{p_i \ | \ i\in I\}.$$

I was thinking that since all quotient maps are open maps I could choose elements $\alpha \in q^{-1}[\{x\}]$ and $\beta  \in q^{-1}[\{y\}]$ and then select disjoint open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively and then show that $q[U] \cap q[V]$ is empty (and that way construct the required neighborhoods to show Hausdorfness). But I ran into a roadblock because I have no way to ensure that $q[U] \cap q[V] = \emptyset$ . For example if $U$ contains a base point $p_j$ and $V$ contains a base point $p_k$ then I'd have $\{[p_i]\} \subseteq q[U] \cap q[V] $.

How can I go about proving the above?

Comment: "..since all quotient maps are open maps.." That is not true. The converse is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Just do it by points.  Pick distinct points $a, b$ in your wedge.  Suppose neither one is the basepoint.  If $a \in X_i$ then we can separate $a$ from $p_i$ by assumption.  Do the same for $b \in X_j$.  Now it's clear those those open sets around $a$ and $b$ respectively remain open in the wedge (because they avoid all basepoints by design) and are still disjoint.  That case is now done.

Now suppose that $a$ is the basepoint in the wedge and $b$ is not.  If $b \in X_j$ then separate $p_j$ from $b$ in $X_j$.  This is given by, say, open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X_j$ with $p_j \in U$ and $b \in V$.  You're then tempted to say that the images of $U$ and $V$ in the wedge do the trick, but that's not so because $q(U)$ probably isn't open:  its inverse image contains $U$ and **all** the basepoints $p_i$ ($i \in I$).  Those other basepoints may not be open in their respective $X_i$.

The fix is simple.  $q(V)$ is still open in the wedge (and contains the "original" $b$) as it doesn't hit the basepoint, so we're fine there.  For the open set about $a$ in the wedge, take
$$
\left( \bigcup_{i \neq j}q(X_i) \right) \cup q(U).
$$
This clearly contains $a$ and avoids $q(V)$, but is it open?  Yes, because its preimage under the quotient map is $\left(\bigcup_{i \neq j} X_i\right) \cup U$ which is open in the disjoint union (before identifying basepoints). The point is that the preimage of $q(U)$ isn't $U$ but is instead $U \cup \{p_i \mid i \in I\}$, but all those basepoints get gobbled up in the open $X_i$, so the total preimage is open as claimed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "If $a \in X_i$"? Because we're picking $a \in \bigvee_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$. Perhaps you meant the picking $a$ in the image of $X_i$ (under the quotient map $q$) which is a subset of the wedge. But in that case we can't "seperate $a$ from $p_i$" because to do that would assume Hausdorffness of the image of $X_i$ in the wedge.

Comment: Most people don’t make a distinction between the term and its  image in their writing.   This is standard abuse of language.